# Async update of HTML element in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to update my DIV asynchronously. In Rails 2.3.8 I found out `remote_form_tag` where I could specify attribute `:update => "DIV_TO_UPDATE"`. As I understood it was an easy way to do update html-element asynchronously, because developer didn't have to write JavaScript code!

But `remote_form_tag` was remoted in Rails 3 and methods `form_for` and `form_tag` don't contain attributes like `:update`. So I wonder if there is a way to do it in Rails 3.1?

PS I know how to do it with a little JavaScript (or CoffeeScript code) I'm looking for way without JS code at all.

Comment: I'm tagging along for the ride on this one, spent the past day (and several others, to be quite honest) trying to figure out the same thing. Hope you don't mind the company.

Answer (score 0):

I believe link_to_function is what you're after: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/link_to_function

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat by redirecting to the same url, if you'd like. It's an expensive operation. (You're just reloading the page, really.)

Horrible, I know. But it's what I did. I'm not very proud. :-(